# MUI DataTable Data not getting displayed in Table, eventhough Data updated with useState variable

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
[data.forEach((originalRow, rowIndex) =>
    accessRow(originalRow, rowIndex, 0, undefined, rows)][1]
```

------useTable.js---

**Even though Data returns to useState still DataTable throws below error when updating rows.** by useTable code line included on the top.
attached the console error.
Function called under useEffect.
The response.data is coming back with the correct data but my table is not reflecting it. Any idea what I could do in order to force update my table to show the new entries?

Console Error

```
useTable.js:591 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
    at accessRowsForColumn (useTable.js:591:1)
    at useTable.js:195:1
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:15846:1)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:16219:1)
    at Object.useMemo (react.development.js:1532:1)
    at useTable (useTable.js:57:1)
    at DataTable (index.js:58:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
```

JS CODE :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import DataTable from "examples/Tables/DataTable";
// import styled from "styled-components";

function LicenseTable() {
  // Here You Set A State To Tell The Component It Need To Wait
  //  Until The Result Is Fetched From The Api
  const [loadingData, setLoadingData] = React.useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const columns = [
    { Header: "Region ID", accessor: "region_id", width: "1%", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Region Name", accessor: "opco_name", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Opco Type", accessor: "RN_session_route_limit", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Session Route Limit", accessor: "opco_type", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Avg Routes", accessor: "prev_average_routes", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Max Routes", accessor: "prev_differ_average", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Diff Average", accessor: "prev_differ_max", align: "left" },
    { Header: "Diff Max", accessor: "current_average_routes", align: "left" },
  ];
  async function getData() {
    await Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/table/latesttest").then((response) => {
      // Check If The Data Is Populated
      console.log(response.data);
      setData(response.data);
      // You Tell It That You Had The Result
      if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {
        console.log("Data set success");
        setLoadingData(false);
      }
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingData) {
      // If The Result Is Not Ready So You Make The Axios Call
      getData();
    }
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* Here You Check If The State Is Loading Otherwise If You Wioll Not Call That You Will Get A Blank Page Because The Data Is An Empty Array At The Moment Of Mounting */}
      {loadingData ? <p>Loading Please Wait...</p> : <DataTable table={{ columns, data }} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default LicenseTable;
```

Comment: under `useEffect`, if `data` changes, what sets `loadingData` to `true` in order to call the `getData()`?

Comment: In my case data will not change and it is static.